# can't load SQLite extension

Tags: c++, sqlite

```
#include <sqlite3ext.h>
...
QVariant v = metaDataBase.driver()->handle();
    if (v.isValid() && qstrcmp(v.typeName(), "sqlite3*")==0) {
        sqlite3 *handle = *static_cast<sqlite3 **>(v.data());
        if (handle != 0) {
            int res = sqlite3_enable_load_extension(handle,1);
            if (res == SQLITE_OK) {
                res = sqlite3_load_extension(handle,"libSqliteIcu.so",0,0);
                if (res == SQLITE_OK) qDebug() << "Sqlite3 loaded ICU extension sucessfully";
                else qDebug() <<  "Sqlite3 failed loading ICU extension";}
            else qDebug() << "Sqlite3 failed enabling load extension";}}
```

and that results in

> 'sqlite3_api' was not declared in this scope

for the line

```
res = sqlite3_load_extension(handle,"libSqliteIcu.so",0,0);
```

how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment in `sqlite3ext.h` says:

> This header file defines the SQLite interface for use by
>   shared libraries that want to be imported as extensions into
>   an SQLite instance.  Shared libraries that intend to be loaded
>   as extensions by SQLite should #include this file instead of
>   sqlite3.h.

Your application is not a shared library.
To make it work, just use `sqlite3.h`.

Comment: thank you! and since i'm using CMake i also had to add a FindSQLite3.cmake file to source/cmake/modules, and FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3 REQUIRED) and TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_app ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY}) to my CMakeLists.txt before it actually worked.